# Optimize Query of Count Less Than

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, optimization

I would like to optimize querying in SQL Server of a table to know whether it has a count of records less than a certain amount. I don't need to know the complete count, just whether it is less than, say, 2.

Would it be efficient to do something like this?...

```
if (
    select count(*)
      from (select top (2) *
              from sys.databases) t
   ) > 1
begin
  select 1
end
else
begin
  select 0
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The query in the question would in principal be able to do this more efficiently than the obvious alternative of just doing `select count(*) from sys.databases`.

For the same reason as `EXISTS` is generally preferable to `COUNT`. It can short circuit.

The `TOP` underneath the aggregate operator can stop requesting rows as soon as the second one is received rather than requesting more and causing additional irrelevant rows to be read.

[image]

It isn't absolutely guaranteed to be more efficient however. There are occasionally edge cases where adding a `TOP` causes a worse overall plan than that for the query which simply brings back the whole result set.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to block and ensure your results are accurate to the nanosecond, you can get this information from DMVs in memory instead of scanning the whole table.

```
IF (SELECT SUM(rows) 
  FROM sys.partitions WHERE [object_id] =         
    OBJECT_ID('dbo.YourTable')) < 2
      PRINT 'less than two';
ELSE 
      PRINT 'two or more';
```

Comment: Wow, I never thought to do it this way. For the query in question, I think we'll stick with the original to keep with consistent code methodology. But very cool. We'll keep this in mind for optimization.